# RegionPlot does not work well when combining two conditions with &&

Tags: plotting, regions

I was trying to use the RegionPlot command to plot a region that satisfies two conditions. I first plotted the two conditions separately with the code:

```
qr1[kr_, kn_, cr_, cn_] := 1/(12 (kn - kr)) (-6 cn + 6 cr + (kn - kr) (6 + 3 kn - 9 kr - 4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + 3 cr + Sqrt[6 cr (-1 + kr)^2 + (-1 + kr)^4] - 2 kr + kr^2]));
qn1[kr_, kn_, cr_, cn_] := (2 cn - 2 cr + 2 kn - kn^2 - 2 kr + kr^2)/(4 kn - 4 kr);

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{qr1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn] >= 0, qn1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn] >= qr1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn]}, 
   {cs, 0, \[Alpha] cn}, {kn, 0, kr}], 
   {{cn, 0.04}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{kr, 0.3}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The picture shows like this:

[image]

Then I combined the two conditions to one with "&&" and tried to plot the overlapping part. The code goes like this:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{qr1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn] >= 0 && qn1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn] >= qr1[kr, kn, cs/\[Alpha], cn]}, 
{cs, 0, \[Alpha] cn}, {kn, 0, kr}], 
{{cn, 0.04}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{kr, 0.3}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

But strangely the plot goes like this:

[image]

The second picture is not showing the overlapping part of the first picture. I may have done something wrong in the code but I couldn't figure out what is it.

Can anyone figure out what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you point out what you think is wrong? As far as I can see, that is the overlapping part.

Comment: Increase the [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html), e.g., `PlotPoints -> 100`

Comment: @Szabolcs As you can see there is some discontinuity at the top right corner of the second pic, while the overlapping part in the first pic is totally continuous. Thanks to Bob's comment problem solved! Seems like there was not enough plotpoints before!